# Application not showing in the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, citrix

We have a credit card program, Ocius.

Unfortunately this does not show in the taskbar and in our citrix environment users can alt-tab to it running as a local application but with windows 7, citrix online plugin and res vdx it doesn't work. after loosing focus users can't get it back, Res VDX can't see it because Ocius doesn't have a taskbar, citrix can't see it because it's a local app and windows 7 won't show it in the alt-tab option.

Is it possible to force a program to run showing in the taskbar?

If not can i program a container (a program that will open Ocius within it) so it will show in the taskbar?

If not is there any program that can bring other programs into focus? E.G

```
BringToFocus.exe /app:Ocius.exe
```

Comment: Can you switch to it from task manager?

Comment: Yes! I never thought of that, unfortunately taskmgr is disabled for our normal users as it was abused.

Comment: what does Ocius say when you ask them why their program hides itself from the windows taskbar?

Comment: They say we need to upgrade to a web based version. This takes time and I was hoping someone could provide a quick answer. I've found the solution and will add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found AutoIT can do this with the following script.

http://www.autoitscript.com

```
If ProcessExists('OCIUS4PC.exe')  Then 
   WinActivate("Ocius");
Else 
   Run("<PATH TO FILE>\OCIUS4PC.exe");
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

The talented Mr. Remko describes here how he worked around a similar problem, forcing an application to appear in the taskbar, even if though it wasn't originally programmed to do that: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/08/04/modify-vb-executable-to-force-taskbar-button/.

This was however for a VB application. Don't know if yours is.